# How do I show an axis in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, axis-labels

How can I re-enable the y-axis on the following line graph?

I have tried right clicking various places with no success.

[image: no y-axis]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right click on the field in the rows shelf and select "show header"

[image]

Comment: Nice. Tableau isn't very nice when it comes to menus. Wouldn't think to use the pill itself.